# Sitecore 7.2 publish increment the data serialization folder Size

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I have a 7.2 sitecore site and when try to do publish the following folder size will be increased automatically, it hit 32 GB on my last publish.

SiteVirtual\Data\serialization

Noticing that I am using a solr search provider.

Comment: Do you use any automated serialization tool like Unicorn or TDS?

Comment: No we do not use unicorn or TDS.

Comment: I would recommend looking into the indexes being updated on publish and the configs that create them

Comment: Can you check your logs if there is any entry about starting serialization?

Comment: That's not default behaviour. Have you added any custom pipelines or event handlers for serialization?

Comment: JRobbins : would you please advise if the specific config in the index configuration may cause the serialization of items.

Comment: jammykam : No there are no custom code on the "OnPublish" event.

Comment: I would recommend looking at your indexes and see if any are particularly large, and post the related config for the largest here

Comment: JRobbins : When rebuild the indexes the serialization folder does not increase , Just when publish.

Comment: Okay, have you written any custom serialisation code, pipelines, processors etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the website is upgraded from sitecore 6.5 the following need to be updated in the web.config to solve this issue:
- Replace

```
<handler type="Sitecore.Data.Serialization.ItemHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" method="OnItemCopied"/>
```

with:

```
<handler type="Sitecore.Links.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" method="OnItemCopied"/>
```

Also replace:

```
<event name="item:renamed">
    <handler type="Sitecore.Data.Serialization.ItemHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" method="OnItemRenamed"/>
  </event>
```

With :

```
<event name="item:renamed"/>
```